# Finding alternatives to SQL Queries

Tags: mysql, sql

Okay so I am trying, Quite unsuccessfully to find alternative methods to these queries to complete the same task, I know many of you will go, *"why change them, they are fine"*.. well As a starting out SQL programmer I want to explore more avenues than I currently have ventured.

**The First Query** should Find a list of the A.names of all contained in table A, without duplication, which have the B.color 'Green'.

```
SELECT A.Name
FROM A
INNER JOIN B 
ON B.AID = A.AID 
WHERE B.Color = 'Green' 
GROUP BY A.AID
```

**The Second Query** should Find  a  list  of  the  A.Names, B.Types and B.Colors for  all  elements in table B that have a B.Price less than  12.00.

```
SELECT A.Name, B.Types, B.Colors
FROM B 
INNER JOIN A 
ON A.AID = B.AID 
WHERE B.Price < '12.99' 
GROUP BY A.AID
```

I am using MySQL within PHPMyAdmin

~Thanks

-Edit - Table A contains, A.AID and A.Name, and Table B contains, B.ID, B.AID, B.Type, B.Color & B.Price

Sorry for any Confusion I may have caused

Comment: it seems unlikely that `a.id = b.id` is the correct join, or it could just be poorly named - could you post the table schema

Comment: MySQL forgives this abuse of the GROUP BY clause. Irritatingly, it even out-performs alternative (correct) solutions. But I would urge a beginner to forgo the use of GROUP BY except in aggregate queries.

Comment: That makes sense, So what kind of alternatives are we talking about here, as a beginner if you could show me some, or point me in the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIRST QUERY**

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.AID, A.Name
FROM A
INNER JOIN B 
ON B.AID = A.AID 
 AND B.Color = 'Green'
```

**SECOND QUERY**

```
SELECT A1.Name, B.Types, B.Colors
FROM B 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT AID, Name
  FROM A 
 ) A1
ON A1.AID = B.AID 
WHERE B.Price < 12.99
```